# What is the default keybinding for <D> on linux? Mac has this bound to Command

Tags: vim, command, key-bindings

Some example settings for Vim (for example [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)) have the command-key  bound to certain commands.

For example:

```
  " Command-Shift-F for Ack
  map <D-F> :Ack<space>
```

I don't know how to find out what that `D` is on my Linux/Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't map to anything on Linux. `:h <D`

```
<D-...>     command-key (Macintosh only)    *<D-*
```

You can substitute other keys, though, like `<C-` is control

Comment: Typing `Ctrl-D` after starting typing a `:help` command may help when you couldn't find the keyword. There are also some other tools, as described in [vimfaq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-4.2).

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux machine `<D` maps to the `\` Key. Maybe meanwhile the key mappings where updated.