# Vim Janus <D-F> <D-/>

Tags: vim, janus

Sorry for such a random question, but while reading [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/) I noticed it offers several shortcuts for things.

I think they are MacVim related and want to know what the Linux equivalents are.

With `<D-F>` `<D-/>` what do the `D`s really stand for? How do I get these commands to work?

Comment: dupity dupity dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639320/what-is-the-default-keybinding-for-d-on-linux-mac-has-this-bound-to-command

Comment: @Andy Ray appears close but different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't read carefully enough.

As much as I despise that kind of "distribution" the authors of Janus have done a great job coming up with Linux/Windows versions (using `Ctrl` or `Alt`) of their Mac OS X specific mappings: see `vim/core/before/plugin/mappings.vim` from [line 60](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/mappings.vim#L60) to [line 160](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/mappings.vim#L160), for example.

To answer your question:

- `<D-/>` is mapped [here,](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim) along with it's Linux/Windows alternatives.
- `<D-F>` is mapped [there,](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/ack.vim) along with it's Linux/Windows alternatives.

The `<A-` mappings may be problematic in most terminals, though.

Comment: according to that it's <//-/> and <//-f> . I for a long time avoided Janus I have got a vimrc a mile long and plugins galore with vundle. But I want to learn vim the editor and CSS / JavaScript / Python but was spending most of my time trying to figure/configure the vimrc . Having said that I instantly had to try and figure out how Janus had set up pep8 and delimitMate. Apparently Janus uses flake8 which currently appears not to work. So I might end up configuring vimrc anyway.

Comment: And found out why the // syntax which is why they use easyMotion https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion.git

Answer (score 4):

`D` stands for the Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command) key. There isn't a Linux equivalent (see `:help <D-`). However, you can remap them to something else.

Comment: @Connor seems odd then that they haven't mapped it to the windows key.

Comment: Certain keys aren't registered by most terminals which greatly limits those kinds of options.

Comment: The Wndows key is pretty much non existant for Vim. Either in the CLI or in GVim.